# Angular 4 View Access Crossing Different Modules

Tags: angular

I am newer using angular 4.

I have two lazy load modules, ShopsModule and SkusModule. In the shop module, I wanna show the list of goods the shop selling, and in the sku module, I wanna show the shops that selling it. 

I tried SharedModule, but it does not seem the right way.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear.

You can navigate from routes in one module to routes in another module. But it sounds like you may only want the data shown on some of the page?

You can build reusable components and add them to any module that needs it.

So you could build a Goods component with a `goodsDisplay` selector. You could then use that component in the Shops component templates or in the Skus component templates.

You would then use a SharedModule to share the Goods component between the two modules.

For an example, check out my shared StarComponent here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted

Comment: Does it mean the shared module should provides both skuService and ShopService？

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. Can you build a plunker to demonstrate your question so we can be sure we are talking about the same thing?